# How to access the upper and lower element of a given element in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some div elements in a sequence, like :

```
 <div id="a"></div>
 <div id="b"></div>
 <div id="c"></div>
 <div id="d"></div>
```

Suppose i have id of 3rd position div which is `c`. Now i want to access the div element which placed just above and below ( in this case b & d respectively ) of div whose id is `c`. How can i do this in jquery?

Comment: `.prev()` and `.next()` (if you're talking about position in a DOM tree).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) and [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/)

```
$('#c').prev();
$('#c').next();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MAd2K/

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this

```
$('#c').prev('div');

$('#c').next('div');
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tM4Rv/1/)

​